# Hibernate logging with slf4j and log4j not generating logfile

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, log4j, slf4j

I'm trying to config my hibernate application to output logging information. I have my log4j.properties configured as follows:

```
{
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\sisco.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout, debug


# Log everything. Good for troubleshooting
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO

# Log all JDBC parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL

}
```

But I think hibernate is not even reading this file, because whatever I set to this file, nothing changes, and also I deleted it, and my application ran normally.

I think that maybe, some other jars in the project might have a log4j.properties file included in the jar, and then hibernate is using it. Does it make any sense?

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have to add this jar into your classpath

```
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar       // the slf4j API
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar   // log4j bindings for slf4j
log4j-1.2.17.jar          // log4j itself
```

that's work for me, good luck ~

Answer (score 0):

The file `log4j.xml` has higher priority than the file `log4j.properties`.

e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//log4j/log4j Configuration//EN" 
                                     "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- console -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="threshold" value="TRACE" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="conversionPattern"
                value="%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.SSS} %-5p (%c.java:%L).%M - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- categories -->
    <category name="org.hibernate">
        <priority value="INFO" />
    </category>
    <category name="org.hibernate.type">
        <priority value="TRACE" />
    </category>

    <!-- root -->
    <root>
        <priority value="TRACE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Since version 1.2.12 of the framework, just need to put it in the *default package* in the `src` folder of your project. log4j automatically load it. No need to load it programmatically or anything extra.